# concatenate dataframes with different shapes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How should I use pd.concat to concatenate df1 and df2 in order to get df3?

```
    df1=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],index=[1,2,2])    
    df2=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[3,4]],index=[2,2])
    df3 =pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,np.nan,np.nan],[3,4,1,2],[5,6,3,4]],index=[1,2,2])  


df1
Out[27]: 
   0  1
1  1  2
2  3  4
2  5  6
df2
Out[33]: 
   0  1
2  1  2
2  3  4
df3
Out[32]: 
   0  1    2    3
1  1  2  NaN  NaN
2  3  4  1.0  2.0
2  5  6  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: You might already know, but if your indexes were unique (i.e. didn't contain multiple 2s), you could just use `df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then is possible use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
df2 = df2.set_index(df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
print (df)
   0  1    2    3
1  1  2  NaN  NaN
2  3  4  1.0  2.0
2  5  6  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: Thanks! if I would like to keep the columns names?

Comment: Try remove `, ignore_index=True`, then it not reset columns names.